# apache 2.4 CustomLog based by response size

Tags: windows, apache, httpd.conf, apache2.4

How can I set the httpd.conf file, to log out based by response size which exceeds the 1Mb?

Here is my code:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    SetEnvIfExpr "%O > 1000000" logio-traffic <===== this is not working
CustomLog "|C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.51/bin/rotatelogs.exe ${INSTALL_DIR}/logs/access.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 5M" combinedio env=logio-traffic
```

Comment: %O is nothing to the expression parser that is used by SetEnvIfExpr. Not sure how to do what you ask, but you could check the possibilities at [expression parser](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html)

Comment: setenvif is also evaluated long before the response size can be known

Comment: @DanielFerradal thanks for suggestion, I looked before that page, but couldn't make to work! This doesn't work: CustomLog logs/access-errors.log common "expr=%O >= 1000000"

Comment: @covener Yes, I also realized it afterwards that I tried few hours to manage the code. This could be work, but I don't know how should write this: CustomLog logs/access-errors.log common "expr=%O >= 1000000"

Comment: Unfortunately I think mod_logio would need an enhancement to make that log format available to expressions. It might be possibly to make any log format format string available and put it in mod_log_config instead.